# Avoiding repetitive code

Tags: c#, loops

This is part of my code

```
double y1 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j1));
double y2 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j2));
double y3 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j3));
double y4 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j4));
double y5 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j5));
double y6 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j6));
double y7 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j7));
double y8 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j8));
double y9 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j9));
double y10 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j10));
double y11 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j11));
double y12 = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j12));
```

`y1`-`y12` and `j1`-`j12` are all separate/different values,

Is there a way to loop so I don't have to write out a line for

```
y1, y2, y3
```

Comment: I've guessed the language based on the questioner's previous questions. Please retag if it's incorrect.

Comment: @Tim ya i forgot to mention it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
double y[12];
double j[12] = {...};

for(int i = 0; i<12; i++){
  y[i]=a/(2 * Math.Sin(j[i]));
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! p.s. if my answer solved your problem, click the big V checkbox to accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of `j`

```
var jArray = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0};
```

you can get an array of `y` like so:

```
var a = 99.99; // or whatever 'a' is
var yArray = jArray.Select(j => a / (2 * Math.Sin(j))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array for those numbers.

It would be like:

```
double[] myArray = new double[12];
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++){
myArray[i] = a / (2 * Math.Sin(j[i]));
}
```